# XML with replaceable PHP variables

Tags: php, xml

I have a question regarding my use of XML. I am using XML as a data storage repositiory. I wanted to use XML to store sentences with variables, inside elements are variables (php) that will be replaced later on by php values/variables once it is retrieved.

I was wondering whether this is the correct use of XML with dynamic variable? Or is there another option to store this kind of data?

Below is an example:

```
<argument-scheme    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:schemaLocation="G:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\argupedia\frontend\arg-scheme-repository\arg-scheme.xsd"
    id='0'
    name='Argument from Sign'
>
    <premise> $paramArray[0] is true in this situation.</premise>
    <premise> $paramArray[1] is generally indicated as true when its sign, $paramArray[0] is true, in this kind of situation."</premise>
    <conclusion>Therefore, $paramArray[1] is true in this situation.</conclusion>
    <critical-question>"Is the correlation between " . $paramArray[0] .  " and " . $paramArray[1] . "strong?"</critical-question>
    <critical-question>Is $paramArray[0] the only event that reliably account for $paramArray[1] ?</critical-question>
    <param-name>Sign</param-name>
    <param-name>Conclusion</param-name>
    <param-question>What is the observation?</param-question>
    <param-question>What is the conclusion that can be drawn from the observation</param-question>
</argument-scheme>
```

Here is an example of how xml is used:

1. First, $paramArray[0] 'Dog hates cats' is inputted and
   retrieved from client.
2. Second, using the above argument scheme xml stored on server, retrieve the 1st premise: "$paramArray[0] is true in this situation".
3. Third, I want to compose the premise in PHP: 'Dog hates cat is true in
   this situation' by replacing '$paramArray[0]' in xml with the user input $paramArray[0] = 'Dog hates cat' using php regex.
4. Finally I want to send 'Dog hates cat is true in this situation'from PHP
   back to the user.

Comment: it's doable - but you're dumping text from php into an xml context, which means php has to output VALID text, e.g. those vars have to be run through `htmlspecialchars()`. Basically you need a templating system that happens to output xml instead of html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was wondering whether there are any xml notation for substitutable variables of a server-side language like PHP or Ruby on rails (not DTD or external XML entities sense)?

Comment: no, there isn't, not unless you `eval()` the xml, which opens up a huge pile of other problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will go with the clunky PHP variable way then